# How to use CommonJS file for tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

A lot of systems (Mocha, ESLint, NYC) give you the option of what format you wish your configuration file to be in (commonjs/js, json, yml, etc).

This can be helpful because in CommonJS (using `module.exports`) you can have comments in your configuration file or other code within your configuration file, which allows a lot of flexibility.

Is there a way to do that in TypeScript and use CommonJS or `module.exports` to define the `tsconfig` file as opposed to just a `json` file?

Answer (score -1):

I'd keep `tsconfig.json` as json and add necessary comments in README.md for example.

Other option is to add comments in json like this:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "//comment": "comment content",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
}
```

If you need more flexibility, you can add a build step to generate `tsconfig.json` from a .js file.

```js
// tsconfig.js
// comments or code here

module.exports = {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
  },
};
```

```js
// tsconfigBuilder.js

const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./tsconfig');

fs.writeFileSync('./tsconfig.json', JSON.stringify(config, null, 2));
```

Add script in `package.json` to generate `tsconfig.json` from `tsconfig.js` before the compiler step.

```js
// package.json

  "scripts": {
    "build-tsconfig": "node tsconfigBuilder.js",
    ...
  },
```

And you're done.